# Probability of heads and tails are $\frac{1}{17}$ and $\frac{16}{17}$ . Find expected number of flips so that at least one head and one tail turns up?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, expected-value

> **QUESTION:** An unfair coin lands heads with probability $\frac{1}{17}$ and tails with probability $\frac{16}{17}$ . Matt flips the coin repeatedly until he flips at least one head and at least one tail. What is the expected number of times that Matt flips the coin?

---

**MY ANSWER:** Assume that $E_h$ is the expected number of moves left after a head turns up and $E_t$ is the expected number of moves left after a tail turns up.. If $E$ denotes the total number of turns Matt has to toss, we can set up relations like -
$$$$
$E=$ $\big($a head turns up$\big)$and$\big($number of moves left until a tail turns up$\big)$ OR $\big($a tail turns up$\big)$and$\big($number of moves left until a head turns up$\big)$
$$\implies E=\frac{1}{17}E_t+\frac{16}{17}E_h$$
Similarly, $E_t=$ if head turns up then sequence is over (since according to our assumption the previous flip was a tail) OR if tail turns up then we start over again..
$$\implies E_t=\frac{1}{17}+\frac{16}{17}E_t$$
Just like this $E_h=$ if a tail turns up then the sequence is over (since the last flip was a head) OR if a head turns up, we start over again..
$$\implies E_h=\frac{16}{17}+\frac{1}{17}E_h$$
Solving the equations we get $E_h$ and $E_t$ both to be $1$.. Which yields $E$ to be $1$..
But this is clearly wrong! $$$$

> I do not understand where is my reasoning wrong? I have presented my logic in clear words before you.. Can someone please correct me..

> Also, is/are there different way/ways to solve this sum? If so, it will be very much helpful if you introduce me to it/them.. Thank You so much..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track, but the precise meaning of your definitions of your quantities $\ E_h\ $ and $\ E_t\ $ isn't very clear, and you've forgotten to count the toss needed to get to your first head or tail.  Your $\ E_h\ $ needs to be the expected number of tosses needed to get a tail *given* that the *first* toss is a head, and your $\ E_t\ $ the expected number of tosses needed to get a head *given* that the *first* toss is a tail.  That these quantities are somewhat confusingly labelled presumably explains why you got the labels reversed in your equation for $\ E\ $,   which should be
$$
E=1+\frac{1}{17}E_h+\frac{16}{17}E_t\ .
$$
Similarly, your equations for $\ E_h\ $ and $\ E_t\ $ should be
$$
 E_h=\frac{16}{17}+\frac{1}{17}\left(E_h +1\right)\\
E_t=\frac{1}{17}+\frac{16}{17}\left(E_t +1\right)\ .
$$
These give you $\ E_h= \frac{17}{16}\ $, $\ E_t=17\ $, and therefore $\ E=17\frac{1}{16}\ $, as Henno Brandsma obtained in his answer.

Comment: Very well explained.. just a doubt before I can accept your answer.. For the equation of $E_h$, if we get a 'tail' in the toss we are done, and if we get a 'head' we start over again... And in either case, we count a toss... So, should it not be $E_h=\frac{16}{17} +\frac{1}{17}E_h +1$... Here $\frac{16}{17}$ denotes we have got a tail, so we don't do anything more.. $\frac{1}{17}$ represents we got a head and so multiply with $E_h$.. While the $+1$ at the end counts a toss either for tail or head.... Where am I wrong?

Comment: The quantity $\ E_h\ $ is the expected number of tosses until you get a tail.  That number is $\ 1\ $ when the next toss is a tail, which occurs with probability $\ \frac{16}{17}\ $, or $\ 1\ $  *plus* the number of *further* tosses to get a tail when the first toss is a head, which occurs with probability $\ \frac{1}{17}\ $ .  Therefore its expected value is $\ \frac{16}{17}\cdot 1 + \frac{1}{17}\left(1+E_h\right)\ .$

Comment: Here's another way of looking at it which may help you recognise the correct equation. The expected number of tosses needed to get your first tail is $1$ plus the expected number of tosses needed *after* the first toss.  The expected number needed after the first toss if it is a tail is $0$, because you've already got your tail, or $\ E_h\ $ if it is a head.  Therefore the expected number is $\ 1+\frac{16}{17}\cdot0+\frac{1}{17}E_h\ $.

Comment: Yes, your immediate last comment was really helpful.. Understood it now.. Thanks a ton!! :D

Answer (score 3):

If $X$ is the number of tosses we still need to throw,  we can condition on the first toss $T_1$:

$E(X) = 1 + E(\text{nr of tosses after } T_1 = t)P(T_1 = t) + E(\text{nr of tosses after } T_1 =h)P(T_1 = h)$, where the $1+$ is to account for the first throw.

$E (\text{nr of tosses after } T_1 = t)$ is just the expectation of a [geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution) with success chance $P(h)=\frac{1}{17}$ so this is $17$.

Similarly  $E (\text{nr of tosses after } T_1 = h)$ is just $\frac{17}{16}$.

So in total we get $$1+ 17\cdot \frac{16}{17} + \frac{17}{16} \cdot \frac{1}{17} = 17\frac{1}{16}$$

Answer (score 0):

The idea of your method is fine as well, but you forget to count the throws you have done. With $E, E_h, E_T$ as you have defined them you namely get
\begin{align*}
E &= \frac{1}{17}(1+E_t) + \frac{16}{17}(1 + E_h),
\end{align*}
as you have to count in the fact that in both cases (heads and tails) you already have thrown once, this should also be counted. Then with your definition of $E_t$ you would e.g. get
\begin{align*}
E_t = \frac{16}{17} + \frac{1}{17}(1+E_t)
\end{align*}
and solving this gives $E_t = \frac{17}{16}$. The same can be done for $E_h$ giving $E_h = 17$ and thus resulting in
\begin{align*}
E = \frac{1}{17}(1 + \frac{17}{16}) + \frac{16}{17}(1 + 17) = 17\frac{1}{16}.
\end{align*}